# mount: / not mounted or bad option

Tags: linux, mount, raspbian, xbmc

I'm running a custom Raspbmc build on my raspberry pi.
On startup, I always see the message

```
mount: / not mounted or bad option
```

The filesystem is still mounted, but still want to know whats causing the trouble.

my */etc/fstab* looks like this:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults,noatime,nodiratime         0       0
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  rw,nosuid,noatime,nodiratime,gid=5,mode=620        0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    ro,noatime,nosuid,nodiratime         0       0
UUID=7e790ee3-660b-46ab-8378-d8ea91730162  /               ext4    defaults,data=writeback,nobh,nodiratime,noatime 0       0
tmpfs           /home/pi/.xbmc/temp     tmpfs   rw,size=5M,nosuid,noexec,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,gid=1000,uid=1000     0       0
/tmp            /var/tmp                none    rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,bind     0       0
```

Comment: There are dedicated Raspberry Pi and Linux sites here on stack exchange that this would be better suited for. Try posting there as you are more likely to get a response.

Comment: I thought mount options would rather fit in a general linux site

Comment: This is the place http://unix.stackexchange.com/ - SO is more about coding rather than sysadmin issues. It can't hurt to post your question there.

Answer (score -1):

I would add "errors=remount-ro" after

```
  ext4      default,errore=remount-ro,...
```

Just try to edit this, let me know-

Comment: That does not get rid of that message. You're having a small spelling mistake in your code (errore)